# database does not open and not mounted

Tags: oracle

After unexpected shutdown the data base not open,

```
`ORA-01507:database not mounted
SQL>alter database mount;
ORA-00214:control file'E:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\CLUSTER\CONTROLFILECONTROLFILE\OO1_MF_HB1484JB_.CTL' version 359456 inconsistent with file 'E:\APP\ADMINISTRATOR\ORAORADATA\CLUSTER\CONTROLFILE\O1_MF_HB114848J_.CTL'
```

I took a copy of both of the control files on external hard drive and replace the less version number with the higher version number, then excuted

````
```SQL> shutdown immediate; 
ORA-01507:database not mounted
ORACLE instance shut down
SQL> startup mount;
Total System Global Area 2221395968 bytes
Fixed size 2177656 bytes
Variable size 1677723016 bytes
Database Buffers 536870912 bytes
Redo Buffer 4624384 bytes 
ORA-00205: error in identiidentifying control file, check alert log for more info
````

Answer (score 0):

One of your control files is either corrupted or contains older version of data than other. Did you run out of storage?

- make copy of both
- overwrite one control file with the other one (smaller by bigger or oldner by newer).
- try to start database

Comment: I replaced the newer version by the older( the one in the or ad at by the one in flash_recovery_area). I simply copy and past, but still don't work and the error  ORA-00205 rises when i try to startup.

Comment: The control file at oradata had a yellow luck before I have deleted but when I past the other one, it doesn't have the yellow luck